# Salida errónea de palabras en java

Tags: java

Estoy leyendo palabras de un fichero y mostrándolas por pantalla de la siguiente forma:

```
try {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader("fichero.txt"));

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}

while(input.hasNext()){

    String palabra = input.next();
    //Elimina el caracter '.' o ',' de una palabra.
    if(palabra.contains(".") || palabra.contains(",")) {
        palabra = palabra.substring(0, palabra.length() - 1);
    }

    System.out.println(palabra);
}
```

Sin embargo, por pantalla hay palabras que salen de la siguiente forma:

m�s

�l

hab�a

El texto me lo han proporcionado y no puedo conocer su encoding. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: huele a que son palabras con tilde (más, él, había). Prueba a poner en UTF-8, si no me equivoco coge las tildes

Comment: Prueba algo como esto: `try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Paths.get("fichero.txt"), "UTF-8")) {
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String palabra = scanner.nextLine();     if(palabra.contains(".") || palabra.contains(",")) {
        palabra = palabra.substring(0, palabra.length() - 1);
    }
    System.out.println(palabra);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}`

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano Java trabaja con UTF-16 por defecto. El problema no creo que sea el encoding del archivo, me parece que es la consola que no soporta dichos caracteres.

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ FileReader trabaja con el encoding por defecto del sistema operativo. Si es windows 7 no usará UTF-8 ni UTF-16

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ estoy utilizando el IDE IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia la codificación del proyecto a UTF-8 o UTF8

Comment: Hola Ugeda. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Para mejorar la respuesta y que no parezca un comentario , has de explicar mejor como tiene que hacer el usuario para configurar lo que dices. MIra [answer] para mejorarla. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

has probado otra forma de leer el archivo , creo que puede ser entre la conversion de fileRader a Scanner ( para ser mas exacto cuando subes un txt con palabras el metodo scanner es el encargado de leerlo entonces el problema debe ser la codificacion, ya que devuelve un "charsetName - The encoding type used to convert bytes from the file into characters to be scanned " )

prueba con un throw - IllegalArgumentException

te recomiendo que revises la api de Scanner ya que es alli radica el problema

PD: aunque no descarto la codificación.

Saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Eso es por el tipo de codificación que estará en alguna que no lea tildes (tipo ASCII). Deberías poner UTF-8. Prueba a añadir esta línea de código.

```
String value = new String(palabra, "UTF-8");
```

Después printealo con:

```
System.out.print(value);
```

Si no te funciona hazlo saber.